# Splash tmux status-right text at start

Tags: tmux

I disabled tmux status-right by set this option: `set -g status-right ''` but when I attach tmux: `tmux a`, there's a text in status right appear and destroyed in a fast way.

tmux 2.7 on archlinux, I use ubuntu wsl to ssh to that arch vm machine. I don't think ubuntu wsl window would cause this issue.

Comment: I can see tmux plugins cause this issue, I tried to isolate by remove all tmux's plugins I had installed. Have no idea what plugin causing this I'll ask in github.

Answer (score 0):

I located this issue from this plugin `tmux-continuum` try to set status-right to one of its script, I'll report to github issue tracker. Another factor that I call `set -g status-right ''` before the call of plugin `set -g @plugin 'tmux-plugins/tmux-continuum'`

Solution is that set status options after plugin-related options, so to make sure status-right get it right.